# Multiple group_by and top_n with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that I am attempting to filter and remove some of the data. That df looks like this:

```
Event    Name    Team    Rank
1        Mike    B       1
1        Joe     A       2
1        Tom     C       3
1        Bill    B       4
2        Joe     A       1
2        Tom     C       2
...
```

I am trying to filter the data so I only have 3 events per person (by their best rank) and 18 people per team.

I was able to get 3 events per person using:

```
df <- df %>% 
group_by(Name) %>%
top_n(-3,Rank)
```

but the 18 people per team is tripping me up. Do I need to `group_by` Team and Name? If so, how? Everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Also, I would prefer to not have ties but that is minor right now.

Edit: this is a large df but here is the structure:

```
structure(list(event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), name = structure(c(22L, 
16L, 28L, 27L, 17L, 21L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 28L, 5L, 16L, 
17L, 2L, 22L, 3L, 10L, 21L, 5L, 15L, 24L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 18L, 25L, 
7L, 21L, 29L, 19L, 25L, 18L, 9L, 23L, 14L, 4L, 29L, 6L, 29L, 
19L, 9L, 26L, 25L, 14L, 4L, 11L, 20L, 12L), .Label = c("Andreas", 
"Andrej", "Blaise", "Brendan", "Coleman", "Colton", "Cooper", 
"Corben", "Eric", "Giovanni", "Graham", "Hayden", "Ian", "Jack", 
"Jacob", "Justin", "Kanoa", "Lane", "Marcelo", "Matthew", "Miles", 
"Nyls", "Robby", "Rodrigo", "Sadler", "T.C.", "Thomas", "Will", 
"Zach"), class = "factor"), team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J"), class = "factor"), rank = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -50L
))
```

Comment: Can you start by making a complete `df` to work with?

Comment: updated with a sample df but the actual one is around 1400 rows.

Comment: what is expected output for your sample dataframe?

Comment: The output should be just like the example dataframe. However each team is only allowed 18 people and each person is only allowed 3 events. So I need to remove the extra people from each team and extra events for the remaining people. I am removing people based on their highest rank. So each team should have 18 people with 3 events after all is said and done.

Comment: Do you need `df %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  top_n(-18, rank) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  top_n(-3,Rank)` ?

Comment: @BillK does my answer help?

Comment: It still isn't correct. I'm sorry I'm having a difficult time describing it. Maybe this is better: Each team needs 18 unique athletes in 3 events for each athlete. I am trying to choose them based on the best rank of their best event. Is there a way to upload a full df?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
df %>% 
group_by(name, team) %>%
filter(row_number() <= 18)
```

@NelsonGon comment advised to group by both at once, which appears to give the exact results in a more concise way.

Comment: I'm away from my PC. Try grouping by both at once.

Comment: I added a df above that should work. Using your code I am getting only 18 rows per team. I need 18 names (all 3 of their events)

Comment: @BillK This is a hard problem to diagnose, your sample df only has a few people with 3 events.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
 library(tidyverse)
    df %>% 
      arrange(team,desc(rank)) %>% 
      group_by(event,team) %>% 
      top_n(3,rank)
```

Current Output:

```
   event name     team   rank
   <int> <fct>    <fct> <int>
 1     2 Giovanni A         9
 2     2 Nyls     A         7
 3     4 Jack     A         7
 4     6 Jack     A         6
 5     3 Andreas  A         5
 6     4 Eric     A         5
 7     2 Justin   A         4
 8     6 Eric     A         3
 9     1 Justin   A         2
10     3 Jacob    A         2
```

test:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(team,desc(rank)) %>% 
  group_by(name,team) %>% 
  top_n(3,rank) %>% 
  filter(name=="Justin")
  event name   team   rank
  <int> <fct>  <fct> <int>
1     2 Justin A         4
2     1 Justin A         2
```